# Replace lines using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have entries in a code that look like this

> hit_power=0.57

These entries have different variables like `0.4`, `0.65`, `0.55` and so on, and there is dozen of them in every file.

I want to replace all `hit_power=` entries with `hit_power=0.5`, but when i try to find `hit_power=` and replace it with `hit_power=0.5` it will replace it but the former argument of function will stay.

For example, I replace `hit_power=0.65` to `hit_power=0.5`, and in the result I will get `hit_power=0.50.65`. How do i remove an entry with `hit_power=` function and replace it with new function and an argument?

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expression matching. Here's how:

Find what: `^hit_power=[0-9.]+$`

Replace with: `hit_power=0.5`

Search Mode: Regular expression

Note: This is just one of the many ways to match the right hand side values.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the regexp in Alex's answer uses `[0-9.]`, but the dot is going to match any character, and I think Alex meant for it to match a literal decimal point. So it should probably be `^hit_power=[0-9\.]+$`, with the dot escaped.

If someone can edit Alex's answer to reflect that, I agree it's exactly the solution I would use.

Comment: The dot inside the square brackets is literal.

Comment: My mistake. I'd forgotten that a dot inside square brackets is a literal dot, not a meta-character, so Alex's answer is spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a tabulator[or few spaces] after hit_power= equation. So it can't find the phrase. So is there any way to find a line with

```
 hit_power=
```

erase the line which the phrase occupy with all marks and arguments after it, and then replace with a new line, with new phrase? 
It would be like this:

Find all lines with

```
hit_power
```

Remove line[s] with hit_power and all spaces,tabs, marks, arguments after it, completely, for example:

> `hit_power=      0.57`
>   `hit_power=      0.43`
>   `hit_power=      0.52`

and replace with

> hit_power=0.5
>       hit_power=0.5
>       hit_power=0.5

The formula that was provided by some answers in this topic, were enough to find hit_power=x and replace it with hit_power=0.5. But it can't find phrase when there are spaces/tabs after = mark.

Here;s the actual code
http://pastebin.com/eLagUcCB

Ok found the answer, just need to use formula

Find

```
hit_power.*
```

Replace with

```
hit_power=0.5
```

Thanks for answers nevertheless!